# Problem with Lualatex arabic personal tcolorbox

Tags: luatex, tcolorbox, babel, arabic

Hello guys I am using lualatex to write in Arabic using latex
but when I use a personalized  tcolorbox it gives me the result in the picture below the next code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\pagestyle{empty}
\newtcbtheorem{defi}{تعريف}%
{ % frame stuff
    enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=white,%green!25!blue,
    colback=white,
    borderline west={3pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},breakable,
    left=0.2cm,
    right skip={-0.029\linewidth},
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top left={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-5mm},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxed title style={boxrule=1pt,rounded corners,colframe=green!25!blue}}{defi}

\begin{document}
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text

\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable]
وشا ضرك
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{defi} 
السلام عليكم لاباس
\end{defi}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think the option enhanced is the source of the problem :'(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `defi` env  is in RTL context  anchors of titlebox are  shifted you need to place `defi` in LTR context with

```
\AddToHook{env/defi/begin}{\textdir TLT \bodydir TLT}
```

Then frame title and frame text must be preceded with `\textdir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT` using `before title` and `before upper` (`before lower`) keys

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\AddToHook{env/defi/begin}{\textdir TLT \bodydir TLT}%

\pagestyle{empty}
\newtcbtheorem{defi}{تعريف}%
{ % frame stuff
    before title=\textdir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT,
    before upper=\textdir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT,
    before lower=\textdir TRT \bodydir TRT \pardir TRT,
    enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=white,
    colback=white,
    borderline east={3pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},
    left=0.2cm,
    right skip={-0.029\linewidth},
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-2mm,xshift=5mm},breakable,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxed title style={boxrule=1pt,rounded corners,colframe=green!25!blue}}{defi}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}{}{}
السلام عليكم لاباس
\end{defi}

\begin{defi}{}{}
السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس

السلام عليكم لاباس
\end{defi} 

السلام عليكم 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Patching `\tikzpicture@tcb@hooked` from skin library also like this give a correct result

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic,layout=graphics]{babel}
\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelfont{rm}{Amiri}

\makeatletter
\bbl@sreplace\tikzpicture@tcb@hooked{\noexpand\tikzpicture}%
          {\textdir TLT\noexpand\tikzpicture}%
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\newtcbtheorem{defi}{تعريف}%
{ % frame stuff
    enhanced,frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=white,
    colback=white,
    borderline east={3pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},
    left=0.2cm,
    right skip={-0.029\linewidth},
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-2mm,xshift=5mm},breakable,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxed title style={boxrule=1pt,rounded corners,colframe=green!25!blue}}{defi}

\begin{document}

\begin{defi}{}{}
السلام عليكم لاباس
\end{defi}
    
السلام عليكم 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution from here: [problem with tcolorbox package and the arabi one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/270516/problem-with-tcolorbox-package-and-the-arabi-one) : Add `fontupper=\selectlanguage{arabic}` to the tcolorbox options.

[image: layout]

Also, you have to tell `babel` which parts are which. (see comment in [tcbraster with two side-by-side lists in English and Arabic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603900/tcbraster-with-two-side-by-side-lists-in-english-and-arabic)).

I made some minor adjustments to the layout,

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[paper width=5cm,paper height=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
%\babelprovide[import,main]{arabic}
\babelprovide[import, onchar = ids fonts]{arabic}
\babelfont[arabic]{rm}[Renderer=HarfBuzz]{Amiri}

\pagestyle{empty}


\newtcbtheorem{defi}{تعريف}%
{ % frame stuff
    enhanced,
%    frame empty,interior empty,
    colframe=green!25!blue,
    colback=blue!10,
    borderline east={3pt}{0pt}{green!25!blue},breakable,
    left=0.2cm,
    right skip={-0.029\linewidth},
    fontupper=\selectlanguage{arabic},
%    fontlower=\selectlanguage{arabic},
    % title stuff
    attach boxed title to top right={yshift=-2mm,xshift=-5mm},
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries\large,
    colbacktitle=green!5,
    boxed title style={boxrule=1pt,rounded corners,colframe=green!25!blue}}{defi}

\begin{document}
Text text text text\par
Text text text text\par
Text text text text



\begin{tcolorbox}\begin{otherlanguage}{arabic}
وشا ضرك 
\end{otherlanguage}
\end{tcolorbox}


\begin{defi}{}{}{\selectlanguage{arabic}}

السلام عليكم لاباس 

\end{defi}



\end{document}
```